# SSRS RDL - Expression SUMS total not by month

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrsgN.png)

Why won't the bad column sum By Month like the Good column?

If you can't view the link , here is another example.  The Bad column = 10 + 20 + 15, instead of the sum per moth, it is summing all months.

Month   Good   Bad
Jan     10     45
Feb     20     45
March   15     45

The RDL code is the same for both expressions:

Good column:  =Sum(Fields!Good.Value)
Bad column:   =SUM(Fields!Bad.Value,"Dataset")

The only difference is the the Good column is in Expression > Categories:  Field and Dataset, while the Bad column is only a dataset.  Also, the Textbox properties are different between the columns are the Bad column is shown as <> rather than the field name.

Does some type of RDL code work to solve this?  Perhaps nested aggregates?  I have tried many things over two days and can't solve the problem.

Thanks a Million

Comment: looks like the column bad is from a different dataset to the good. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `, "Dataset"` part of the bad expression.

The Good expression is only summing values within the scope of the textbox, so that is probably by a rowgroup that is grouping by month. By specifying the dataset, like you have in the Bad expression, you are telling SSRS to sum the values within the scope of the entire dataset.